# Odbcad32.exe file corrupted

Tags: excel, jdbc, driver

I cannot set up excel ODBC drivers from the data sources in control panel. The excel drivers are not shown in the list.

I have tried the odbcad32.exe file in Windows/syswow64 folder, I could set it up with that file, but couldn't set it up with the file in `windows\system32`. 
And the JDBC program couldn't connect to the driver.

The odbcad32.exe file in syswow64 was working, so I replaced the same file in system32 with this file. This way I was able to create the driver.
But on running the JDBC program, I'm getting this error

> The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

I'm using windows7 64 bit. Office 2007

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mix 32 and 64 bit versions of `odbcad32.exe`. I think it is bad that both 32 and 64 bit versions have the same name, but this is how MS build it. In `system32` there is 64 bit version of `odbcad32.exe`. In `windows/syswow64` there is 32 bit version of `odbcad32.exe`.

Configuration of ODBC is stored in registry. Native, 64 bit applications including `odbcad32.exe` use:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI
```

If you use such registry location from 32 bit apps then Windows redirects it to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBC.INI
```

You will find more about registry redirection at:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305097

If any of your ODBC administrative programs is corrupted do not exchange it with versions from other directories, do not mix 32 and 64 bit versions. The only solution I see is to clean install them from CD or copy them from other machine.